# How should java comparator class be declared to sort the array by there second element in ascending and descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

```
int arr[][] = new int[][] {
            {3, 7},
            {1, 2},
            {8, 9},
            {4, 2},
            {5, 3},
            {0,90}
        };
```

this is my array ,i can sort it ascending or descending order based on there first element using
bellow code :

```
Arrays.sort(arr,(a,b)->Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));
```

Now my question is how to do the same thing using second element on the array.

Comment: Use `a[1]` and `b[1]` instead of `a[0]` and `b[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the first element with index `0` you want to access the second element using index `1`, i.e., `a[1]` and `b[1]`.

I suggest you should read up on [how to use arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), since this question is not specific to sorting but shows a lack of understanding arrays in general.